# Issue with CSS; captcha overflowing form boundaries

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap, css, captcha

I'm working on a website redesign based on the Bootstrap 3 framework.

In configuring the site's contact form, and implementing a captcha, I've run into an issue with my CSS.

Everything works well in Chrome, but in Firefox, the captcha overflows the form boundaries, and is off to the side, whereas in Chrome, it's under the form and integrated more normally. To attempt to fix this, I put the captcha (which was outside of the form's div tags originally) inside it's own div group. That fixed part of the issue, in properly aligning the captcha under the rest of the form.

However, now that I've done that, the captcha (and the form label it's associated with) overruns the form boundaries on both sides, and doesn't display properly in either Chrome or Firefox. Further, it doesn't space properly, despite being in its own div.

http://www.weatherworks.com/contact/contact.php

I'm not sure how - or if - I can fix this. I'm a student and web design is more of a hobby for me; I'm actually doing this redesign as part of a weather-related internship. I'm fairly knowledgeable on HTML and CSS, but am pretty lost with this issue. Was hoping someone here who's worked with forms and/or Bootstrap might have some insight for me.

Thanks!

Comment: in html `<div class="form-group" id="commentTxt">` close the tag of div above the next `<div class="form-group">`

Comment: `</div> <!-- Add this div -->    
<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-lg-2 control-label">Verify Humanity</label>`

Comment: Thanks! Feel really dumb now... I had a feeling it was something simple, but not *that* simple. I completely missed the missing tag - it wasn't showing up as missing within the nested structure of my editor and I was sure the issue was in my CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed a closing tag of the `<div class="form-group" id="commentTxt">`. Place a close tag above the next `<div class="form-group">`

```
<div class="form-group" id="commentTxt">
.
.
.   
</div> <!-- Add this div --> 
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">Verify Humanity</label>
```

Comment: Thanks! A simple code mis-read on my part... I've been staring at my pages all day and was sure it was a more involved CSS issue. Glad a second pair of eyes could resolve it. :-)